# Django Queryset with Latest of Foreignkey

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have 3 linked Django models.

`models.py`

```
Assessment(models.Model):
    finalized = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finalized_date = models.DateTimeField(default=blank, blank=True)
    workstation = models.ForeignKey(Assessment, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    class Meta:
         get_latest_by = "finalized_date"

Workstation(models.Model):
    pass

Answer(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(Assessment, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**Here is my 1st problem:**

I need a queryset that returns all the assessments that are the latest (L).

For example where (L) is latest:

```
Workstation 1    |   Workstation 2    | Workstation 3
------------------------------------------------------
Assessment 1 (L) |  Assessment 12     | Assessment 4
Assessment 2     |  Assessment 41     | Assessment 15 (L)
Assessment 3     |  Assessment 99 (L) | Assessment 9
```

So the query set should return: `Assessment 1, Assessment 99 and Assessment 15`

I thought about doing a queryset of Workstations and then doing a `for` loop but that is too costly and spawns a LOT of queries.

**Second Problem (related to the first):**

I actually need a queryset of all the Answers associated with the latest assessments by workstation.

I thought that I could break it down into several querysets in order to get it to work, but if there is a way to do this from one queryset please educate me!

So once I have that queryset of Assessments from #1, I'll just use the follow querysets to get what I actually need.

`final_queryset = Answer.objects.filter(assessment__in=QuerySet_From_Problem_1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question**

First, I think your `Assessment -- Workstation` relation is inverted. According to what you ask, a `Workstation` can have multiple `Assessments`, so the models should be:

```
Assessment(models.Model):
    workstation = models.ForeignKey(Assessment, null=True, 
                                    blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    finalized = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finalized_date = models.DateTimeField(default=blank, blank=True)

    class Meta:
         get_latest_by = "finalized_date"

Workstation(models.Model):
    pass
```

Now, to get what you want you can make use of the [`Subquery` feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) that was introduced in Django 1.11:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
latest = Assessment.objects.filter(
    workstation=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-finalized_date')

workstations = Workstation.objects.annotate(
    latest_assessment_id=Subquery(latest.values('pk')[:1]))
for workstation in workstations:
    print('Assessment {}'.format(workstation.latest_assessment_id))
```

**Second question**

Now that you have the assessment ids, as you say, you just have to get the answers:

```
latest_assessments_ids = (w.latest_assessment_id for w in workstations)
answers = Answer.objects.filter(assessment_id__in=latest_assessments_ids)
```

Comment: you're the best. Thank you very much!